# Google Sheet Formula - Vlookup multiple tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to lookup for data in multiple tabs (so far I have 20 sheets). I just want to import the status information when someone selected the dropdown. I used the formula below

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(D5:D,{EVENTS!A1:E4,CURRICULUM!A1:E2,DATA!A1:E2,'STUDENT EXPERIENCE'!A1:E2,Alderink!A1:E2,Bishop!A1:E2,'Bishop, Booker'!A1:E2,Booker!A1:E2,'Booker, Events'!A1:E2,'Booker, Davis'!A1:E2,'Booker, Coughlin'!A1:E6,'Booker, Giles'!A1:E2,'Booker, Cramer'!A1:E2,Coughlin!A1:E3,'Coughlin, Shepard'!A1:E2,'Daley, Booker'!A1:E2,Dutkiewicz!A1:E2,'Dutkiewicz, HR'!A1:E2,'Epstein, Booker, Coughlin'!A1:E2,'Fortier, Giles'!A1:E2,'Giles, HR'!A1:E2,Gunn!A1:E2,Lawrence!A1:E6,'Lawrence, Gely'!A1:E2,Lowe!A1:E2,'Lowe, Enge'!A1:E2,Niedzielski!A1:E3,'A. Miller'!A1:E3,'A. Miller, Lawrence'!A1:E2,'A. Miller, Events'!A1:E2,'M. Miller'!A1:E2,Montanino!A1:E3,Shelton!A1:E2,Shull!A1:E2,Sneath!A1:E5,'Sneath, Coughlin, Booker'!A1:E2,Stahley!A1:E2,Stevenson!A1:E2,Veneklase!A1:E2,Wiggins!A1:E2}3,1))
```

It seems it gives me an error. I am just trying to avoid copy and paste when multiple contributors inputting information. Created different sheets for each contributor and I want the data to be populated in summary tab when they input information in another tab.

Comment: I believe you are using a comma where you should be using a semi-colon.  A comma combines the ranges horizontally, so you are adding more columns with each additional range.  A semi-colon stacks them.   https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/use-curly-brackets-to-create-arrays-in-google-sheets/

Comment: I actually fixed it! Yes, the semi-colon does impact it and I need to lock it too.